# how to route multiple html pages correctly using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a basic knowledge of AngularJS only. I have created one AngularJS application with multiple html pages. This is my main view html.Im so sorry my question is so long.But this is better way to ask my question.

**Main.cshtml**

```
    <html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Main</title>
    <!-- Main CDN Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- end-->
    <link href="~/Content/Css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        * {
            border-radius: 0 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav-side-menu">
 //some code
</div>
<div class="nav-top-menu nav-top">
 //some code
</div>
<div class="contents" id="subContents" ui-view>
 //route my sub views to here
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/smart-table.debug.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MainView.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**MainView.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"]);
myapp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")
    $stateProvider
      .state('sideMenuCustomerDivition', {
          templateUrl: "Main/Customer"
      })
      .state('sideMenuDashboardDivition', {
          templateUrl: "Main/Staff"
      })
})
```

i have route my another html view into main.cshtml.This is html of that view

**Customer.cshtml**

```
<html>
 <body ng-app="customerTableApp">
  <div ng-controller="safeCtrl">

        <button type="button" ng-click="addRandomItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
            </i> Add random item
        </button>

        <table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
                    <th st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
                    <th st-sort="birthDate">birth date</th>
                    <th st-sort="balance">balance</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="5"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" /></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
                    <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" ng-click="removeItem(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
                            </i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/CustomerView.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**CustomerView.js**

```
var app = angular.module('customerTableApp', ['smart-table'])
app.controller('safeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    var firstnames = ['Laurent', 'Blandine', 'Olivier', 'Max'];
    var lastnames = ['Renard', 'Faivre', 'Frere', 'Eponge'];
    var dates = ['1987-05-21', '1987-04-25', '1955-08-27', '1966-06-06'];
    var id = 1;

    function generateRandomItem(id) {

        var firstname = firstnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        var lastname = lastnames[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        var birthdate = dates[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
        var balance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);

        return {
            id: id,
            firstName: firstname,
            lastName: lastname,
            birthDate: new Date(birthdate),
            balance: balance
        }
    }

    $scope.rowCollection = [];

    for (id; id < 5; id++) {
        $scope.rowCollection.push(generateRandomItem(id));
    }
    $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.rowCollection);
    $scope.addRandomItem = function addRandomItem() {
        $scope.rowCollection.push(generateRandomItem(id));
        id++;
    };
    $scope.removeItem = function removeItem(row) {
        var index = $scope.rowCollection.indexOf(row);
        if (index !== -1) {
            $scope.rowCollection.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I know the problem is ng-app routed into another ng-app.Anyone can give me better solution for this.Template already routed in to view. my problem is I can't assign values in to second view.Customer view is display in side main view.But assigned values not displayed.Browser shows that type of error.

> Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/ng/areq?p0=safeCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
>       at Error (native)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:6:416
>       at Qb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:19:417)
>       at sb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:20:1)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:76:95
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:57:257
>       at s (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:7:408)
>       at v (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:57:124)
>       at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:52:9)
>       at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js:51:118

Comment: If Customer.cshtml is supposed to be a view, it should not be a full html document.  Strip off the top level html and body tags, so the top level tag is div.

Answer (score 1):

It might Help you!!

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            templateUrl: 'index.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
          })
        .state('index.test', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'TestCtrl'
          })
        .state('app', {
            templateUrl: 'app.html',
            controller: 'AppController'
          })
        .state('app.test2', {
            url: '/test2',
            templateUrl: 'test2.html',
            controller: 'Test2Controller'
          })
});
```

And the other example

```
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          '@' : {
            templateUrl: 'layout.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
          },
          'top@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.top.html',},
          'left@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.left.html',},
          'main@index' : { templateUrl: 'tpl.main.html',},
        },
      })
    .state('index.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
      })
    .state('index.list.detail', {
        url: '/:id',
        views: {
          'detail@index' : {
            templateUrl: 'detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl'
          },
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but

One of the first things I'll note is that you should pass in the controller from the state. You can have `.state('statename', { templateUrl: 'templateName', controller: controllerName });`

Also, you can specify the url you want associated with the route by using the url tag inside the state config object.

`.state('sideMenuCustomerDivition', {
    url: '/route1',
    templateUrl: 'Main/Customer',
    controller: 'safeCtrl'
});`

Now if you navigate to the route with url /route1, the template should be inserted in the ui-view

Comment: template already routed in to view. my problem is i cant assign values in to second view.